# Why can't I deploy my next.js app to port 80?

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, next.js, cpanel

I never deployed any project before and I'm currently running with an issue while deploying a next.js app to godaddy. I uploaded my next.js app to the public_html folder of my cpanel and then i connected through ssh and executed the npm run dev command with server.js pointing to my domain name as hostname and 3000 as port number however, to access it i will have to write in the url [www.mydomain.com:3000](http://www.mydomain.com:3000) . I learned that in order to access it by the following url [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) I have to specify port 80 in the server.js file. However, when I do so and run the npm run dev command it says that I do not have the permission to port 0:0:0:0:80
[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqRXd.png)

I have a VPS server and a domain name. I am doing something wrong or is there something I missed? Should I not use my domain name as hostname in the server.js file? Should I maybe keep the hostname as my VPS ip and port 3000 then point my domain to read from this address? I am a beginner with no previous exprience in deployement and this is my first next.js app ever.

Any help is appreciated and thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question is probably more of a better fit for another StackExchange site like SuperUser, but I'm also sure it's a question that's been asked and answered before. By default, only the root user can open ports below 1024, which is why you're getting permission errors.

Comment: @AaronD Thank you for your comment, I have tried to run the npm run dev command as a root user and with the root user itself and it still gave me the same permission error

Comment: Yes, it's not a good idea to run your application as root in any case. You might want to look at running it on the default port 3000, and using a web server or firewall rule to reroute incoming traffic on port 80/443 to the application instead. For example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/444729/redirect-port-80-to-8080-and-make-it-work-on-local-machine

Comment: @C999s I wouldn't hard hardcode a port number in `server.js` like that. I typically have a reverse proxy setup that forwards API requests to the Node server on port 3000 while handling everything else on port 80. But to keep things simple while you wait for answers (I'm unfamiliar with cpanel hosting), you can have the Next.js server start on a different port with the `-p` flag like this: `"start": "next start -p 80"`.

Comment: @AaronD Thank you for your answer! I have no idea how to do this but I'll look into it

Comment: @MarkG Thank you for your answer! I'll search more how to do this on my vps server